# Remember ICQ feature "Symbolic language"? (look-alike to pre-school educational material - icq5 4 6 ~ 2005 2006 qip nostalgia)

Tags: icq, aim, miranda-im

Please help to rediscover this.   How was/is it called?

What license, free/open source?  What else did the developers do?

Part of which version exactly?

- **Detailed:** There used to be this feature (or plugin?) included in one ICQ version near 2005, which was basically powered by a dictionary full of icons like emoticons  representing words. When activated the feature would accompany any common word in every message by those cliparts. I think it was switched ON by default in at least one ICQ version *(Possibly though, even though unlikely, it was only in german versions, maybe one of those advertised by pro7 / sat1. Anyway i will translate the title for google: "Errinert ihr euch an die ICQ Funktion: symbolsprache / kleine icons?")*
- **Use:** It could support reading or simply make reading more fun (similar to some pre-school books where each word is also accompanied by an icon) - Yet no-one really expected the feature and to take so much additional space for every message and it was gone soon.
- **Use Today:**  I'm researching this kind of application extensively. 
  Especially if it is licenced CreativeCommons, then it may still be useful/worth to be rediscovered to some more people over time. *(- So this is not just nostaliga - While it may not be necessary to give reasons to ask questions still premature moderation induced pain previously... All tags of this questions have none or few questions per year. So everyone following the tags may be happy with any question. Please just edit if anything.)*